# Button press hold error on TextView and ImageView

Tags: android, button, textview, imageview, ontouch

I have a `Button`, `TextView(number)` and an `ImageView`. Every time I press the button the number will increment. It will increment a lot faster when I hold the button.
I want to show an image at a specific number using `ImageView` at the same time making the button visible to `INVISIBLE` for a while to stop the increment.

**The problem:** If I press the button one click at a time then the below code functions well but as I hold down the button, the image appears for a very short while and continue with the numbers. And although the button is set invisible for 5 seconds, the numbers still increases(as the button is still hold).

**MAIN CLASS**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
TextView textView;
ImageView imageView;
int i=0;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnTouchListener(new RepeatListener(400, 100, new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setText();
            setImage();
        }
    }));
}

public void setText(){
    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textView.setText(""+i);
    i++;
}
public void setImage(){
    if(i==10){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.kitten);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonInvi();
    }
}
public void buttonInvi(){
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 5000); // where 1000 is equal to 1 sec (1 * 1000)
}
}
```

**RepeatListener CLASS**

```
public class RepeatListener implements OnTouchListener {

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private int initialInterval;
private final int normalInterval;
private final OnClickListener clickListener;
private View touchedView;

private Runnable handlerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(touchedView.isEnabled()) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, normalInterval);
            clickListener.onClick(touchedView);
        } else {
            // if the view was disabled by the clickListener, remove the callback
            handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
            touchedView.setPressed(false);
            touchedView = null;
        }
    }
};
public RepeatListener(int initialInterval, int normalInterval,
                      OnClickListener clickListener) {
    if (clickListener == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null runnable");
    if (initialInterval < 0 || normalInterval < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative interval");

    this.initialInterval = initialInterval;
    this.normalInterval = normalInterval;
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
            handler.postDelayed(handlerRunnable, initialInterval);
            touchedView = view;
            touchedView.setPressed(true);
            clickListener.onClick(view);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
            touchedView.setPressed(false);
            touchedView = null;
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: use clickListner instead of onTouchListner

Answer (score 0):

How about checking the visibility before increasing the counter

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
                handler.postDelayed(handlerRunnable, initialInterval);
                touchedView = view;
                touchedView.setPressed(true);
                clickListener.onClick(view);
            }
            return true;    
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            if(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                handler.removeCallbacks(handlerRunnable);
                touchedView.setPressed(false);
                touchedView = null;
            }
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line

`button.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

instead of

```
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: its just the same as view invi. tried it and this doesnt work. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just set your `listener to null` when you reach a specific number and show `imageview` and make `button invisible` then after 5 seconds again set your listener and make `button visible`